# Constraint Layout background hides when scroll view background is added in Android Studio 2.3.1

Tags: android, xml

When a background is set for a constraint layout then a scroll view is added with its own background as a child of the constraint layout. The constraint layout background disappears, why ?

Comment: Is your scroll View fully covering the parent constraint layout? If so its pretty obvious that the scrollview will override the background of constraint layout.

Comment: You are right, the scrollview background was overriding the parent background. I had this before for the constraint layout:

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"


I changed it to this:

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Answer (score 0):

Bilal, You are right, the scrollview background was overriding the constraint layout (parent background). I had this before for the constraint layout:

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

I changed it to this:

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Then it placed the scrollview background on top of the parent background.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation where i had a constraintlayout -> ScrollView ->Linearlayout

Following 2 steps should resolve this:

1. Set **layout_width** of linearlayout as **match_parent**
2. Set left and right constraints for ScrollView